# fixed header on scroll with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, nav

how do i make my menu to stay fix to the top of screen as the user scroll down a page?
i have a **nav** tag with class of **.nav-secondary genesis-responsive-menu** and inside that nav there's a list of menu item..
So right now if someone scroll down a page the navigation disappears, how do i make my header fixed?

```
<nav class="nav-secondary genesis-responsive-menu" aria-label="Secondary" id="genesis-nav-secondary">
 <div class="wrap">
  <ul id="menu-after-header-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2571"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2567"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3644"></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the link to it to get a better understanding of the code:
[myksa.net](https://myksa.net/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.nav-secondary{
position:sticky;
top:0;
}
```

That tells the browser to keep the item sticky once it hits 0 from the top

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign a position attribute to the nav element and give it a value of "fixed".

```
.nav-secondry{
position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav.secondary {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Also make sure to set a white background to your whole navigation and you can use z-index to set it to display above all other elements.

Comment: Why are you talking about "white background"? Moreover, you should explain a little more your answer.